# is there any way to monitor secret rotation failed in aws secret manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-secrets-manager

I want to create a cloud watch alarm to monitor secrets rotation and triggers if RotationFailed.

I have checked the aws documentation about RotationFailed. [This document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#monitoring_cloudwatch_deleted-secrets_part3) says,

```
RotationFailed event - a mechanism to inform you that secret rotation failed for an application.
```

but I cant find how to use RotationFailed event to trigger alarm. please help me to create metric filter and alarm for secret rotation failed.

Comment: I need to create a  cw alarm using terraform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this cloudwatch event

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.secretsmanager"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "RotationFailed"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: but in cloud trail I dont see any event name called RotationFailed. I will try and update here.

Comment: do you have any idea how to create alarm with this event using terraform file

Comment: Refer to the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_rule